# Delete last N characters from field in a T-SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I have table of over 4 million rows and accidentally in one column there is more data than needed.

For example instead of `ABC` there is `ABC DEFG`.

How can I remove that N symbols using TSQL? Please note that I want to delete this characters from database, NOT just select substring. Thank you

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable SET column=LEFT(column, LEN(column)-5)
```

Removes the last 5 characters from the column (every row in mytable)

Comment: When I use multiple Update statements as per your answer. It work for first update statement and for others I get error : Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. Please help

Comment: @NikhilPatel UPDATE mytable SET column=LEFT(column, LEN(column)-5) and LEN(column) > 5

Comment: This solution works in the special case when there are more than 4 charactersin `column`  (which is the case for the OP)  but fails otherwise.

Comment: Not exactly what I was doing, but this helped me build my logic. Thanks a million.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this looking for a solution in MySQL, this same answer works, just replace `LEN()` with `LENGTH()` or `CHAR_LENGTH()`.

Answer (score 15):

I got the answer to my own question, ant this is:

```
select reverse(stuff(reverse('a,b,c,d,'), 1, N, ''))
```

Where N is the number of characters to remove. This avoids to write the complex column/string twice

Answer (score 4):

You could do it using `SUBSTRING()` function:

```
UPDATE table SET column = SUBSTRING(column, 0, LEN(column) + 1 - N)
```

Removes the last N characters from every row in the column

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, removing characters from the left by one or however many needed.

```
lEFT(columnX,LEN(columnX) - 1) AS NewColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function RIGHT [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_right.asp]

RIGHT( "string" , number_of_chars_from_right_to_left)

That should look like this:

```
Query: SELECT RIGHT('SQL Tutorial', 3) AS ExtractString;
Result: "ial"
```

Comment: The requester wants the remove the right part, not select it.